# Which return type to use for an action method that can return an anonymous type, but also HTTP status codes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I see that there are multiple ways I can return data in Asp.Net Core controller when various results are possible:

1) `object`

```
[HttpPost]
public object RefreshToken()
{
    if (Validate())
    {
        return new
               {
                   token = CreateToken()
               };
    }

    return HttpUnauthorized()
}
```

2) `dynamic`

```
[HttpPost]
public dynamic RefreshToken()
{
    if (Validate())
    {
        return new
               {
                   token = CreateToken()
               };
    }

    return HttpUnauthorized()
}
```

3) `IActionResult`

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult RefreshToken()
{
    if (Validate())
    {
                return new ObjectResult(new
                {
                    token = CreateToken()
                });
    }

    return HttpUnauthorized()
}
```

Are there any differences with these 3 approaches? Which one should be preferred?

Comment: None of the above; what about type safety?

Comment: Why do you want to return an anonymous type?

Comment: Well, what kind of type safety can you expect if it will be converted to json, the result won't be used anywhere. But generally it's just much more convenient to return it right away like that, rather than creating a special class for each method.

Comment: There is another reason though as well, if you want to return HttpUnauthorized() if something goes wrong, then you cannot use type-safe result.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik isn't an `HttpUnauthorized` handled under `IActionResult`?

Comment: It is handled in fact in all 3 cases that I described.

Comment: If your code don't need to return the values like `HttpNotFound`, then you don't need `IActionResult`. The return type `dynamic` seems be not the best choice in the return value. It can be good for internal calculations (if you use `ExpandoObject` or `DynamicObject`). Thus, in my opinion, `object` would be the best choice as the type of returned value in your case. If you would need to report error messages for example then `IActionResult` next option.

Comment: @Oleg Actually in asp.net core all 3 cases work with error results.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: What you mean with work with error results? I would expect that all 3 options do works without problems.  At least I don't see any errors.

Comment: @Oleg, sorry, I meant that with all 3 options it will return 404 if you return  HttpNotFound.

Comment: `IActionResult` seems the most reasonable to me. Clearer in intent, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, the question is mostly about the style of writing the program, because all the options will be called in the same way.

MVC execute all the Actions in the same way. [The line](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/ControllerActionExecutor.cs#L45) with `invocationResult = actionMethodInfo.Invoke(instance, orderedActionArguments);` (where I placed `!!!` in comments) calls the controller action:

```
public static Task<object> ExecuteAsync(
    MethodInfo actionMethodInfo,
    object instance,
    object[] orderedActionArguments)
{
    object invocationResult = null;
    try
    {
        invocationResult = actionMethodInfo.Invoke(instance, orderedActionArguments); // !!!
    }
    catch (TargetInvocationException targetInvocationException)
    {
        // Capturing the exception and the original callstack and rethrow for external exception handlers.
        var exceptionDispatchInfo = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(targetInvocationException.InnerException);
        exceptionDispatchInfo.Throw();
    }

    return CoerceResultToTaskAsync(
        invocationResult,
        actionMethodInfo.ReturnType,
        actionMethodInfo.Name,
        actionMethodInfo.DeclaringType);
}
```

The results will be interpreted always as `object` (`object invocationResult`). Then the method `CoerceResultToTaskAsync` tests whether the type of return object is `Task` and if not, converts it to Task. Then the outer method (inside of `var actionReturnValue = await ControllerActionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(...);`) returns the value [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/ControllerActionInvoker.cs#L103-L106) and `CreateActionResult` tests in [the lines](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/ControllerActionInvoker.cs#L131-L135) (`var actionResult = actionReturnValue as IActionResult; if (actionResult != null) { return actionResult; }`) that the returned result have `IActionResult` interface. If not, then one returns `new ObjectResult(...)`. See below the copy of the code

```
internal static IActionResult CreateActionResult(Type declaredReturnType, object actionReturnValue)
{
    if (declaredReturnType == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(declaredReturnType));
    }

    // optimize common path
    var actionResult = actionReturnValue as IActionResult;
    if (actionResult != null)
    {
        return actionResult;
    }

    if (declaredReturnType == typeof(void) ||
        declaredReturnType == typeof(Task))
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }

    // Unwrap potential Task<T> types.
    var actualReturnType = GetTaskInnerTypeOrNull(declaredReturnType) ?? declaredReturnType;
    if (actionReturnValue == null &&
        typeof(IActionResult).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(actualReturnType.GetTypeInfo()))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            Resources.FormatActionResult_ActionReturnValueCannotBeNull(actualReturnType));
    }

    return new ObjectResult(actionReturnValue)
    {
        DeclaredType = actualReturnType
    };
}
```

In other words, all the code do the same. The first option, which returns `object`, and the last one will work identical. I personally would prefer to use the first option to have no explicit call of `ObjectResult`, but in other cases the last version with `IActionResult` is readable enough. It's more the matter of the taste.